# PHP Paypal Error processIpnRequest

Tags: magento-1.9, php, paypal, supee-7405

I recently noticed an error in my apache logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function processIpnRequest() 
on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers
/IpnController.php on line 43
```

I'm not sure what might be causing this issue, but it does seem to show up whenever a Paypal payment goes through the site (though the payments seem to go through successfully).  Any thoughts on what might be causing it?

Comment: Make sure that the following file `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Ipn.php` exists in your system and it contains class `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn`

Comment: @Yaroslav Rogoza:  Thanks for the reply!  I checked, and sure enough the file exists and contains that class.  Not sure what might be causing the error to appear, it seems odd.